# Linear Transformations with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello everyone, I'm just confused as to wear to start with this question. Should I create a matrix from the polynomials given to me before the equals sign or after the equals sign? Is that the correct intuition to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would try to express $2-3x$ in terms of $\alpha(1+4x)+\beta(4+15x)$ and then uses the linearity of the transformation, and the given information.

Comment: Although it wasn't as fast (or smart) as the other methods suggested, I went for brute force and represented $T$ as the matrix $\mathbb{A}$ and solved the two resulting equalities simultaneously, where $$\mathbb{A} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Find $T(1)$ and $T(x)$ by using the fact that $T$ is linear, i.e. $T(\alpha_1 p_1+\alpha_2p_2)=\alpha_1T(p_1)+\alpha_2T(p_2)$ for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $p_1,p_2 \in P_1$.